# how to display the data in a data table from ajax call in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

i have a bootstrap 3.2.0 theme. i want to display mysql's data using data-table

Here is what i tried in jquery

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#customerApplication').dataTable( {
            jQuery.ajax: ({ url: "<?php echo base_url("customer/index"); ?>"                 });
        } );
    } );    

</script>
```

But it is showing table without pagination and other options

How it can be modified to display the table in right format